# Subtyping and Module Inclusion in OCaml

Tags: module, ocaml, subtype

Suppose I have the following setup

```
module type FOO = sig type f val do_foo : f end
module type BAR = sig type b val do_bar : b end


module type FOOANDBAR =
  sig 
    include FOO
    include BAR
  end
```

Now I want to (in a nice way, aka, without copying the interface and so that FOO and BAR are still subtypes) enforce the restriction that the type f and the type b are the same.

Is there a nice way to do this in OCaml, possibly using some different approach that the include keyword?

thanks!!
-Joseph

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
module type FOOANDBAR =
  sig 
    include FOO
    include (BAR with type b = f)
  end
```

Comment: Gracias!  (Today is my second day with OCaml, and this is all very confusing, but that is super easy)

Comment: What is the difference between `include (BAR with type b = f)` and `include (BAR with type b := f)`? The latter one "brutally" substitutes `b` with `f`.

Comment: @lukstafi: w`:=` is a destructive substitution that changes the signature instead of only refining it with equalities. I think either one would be fine in this case, but I used `=` as it is simpler and has been available for a long time, while `:=` was only added in OCaml 3.12.